# Try it out functionality of tmdb api not working

Tags: api, themoviedb-api

When I tried to see data through **try it out** functionality then it is showing the following error

Error: Network Error

Check the developer tools console, it might have more information on the error.

If you are using an Adblocker, it is possible your Adblocker is blocking the request.

I also tried after disabling adblocker but it also does not work

console showing like this

[image: console image]

Why this is happening and what is the solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Am also facing the same issue. But copy pasting the generated URL in new tab works fine.

Comment: yes this will work

Answer (score 1):

Try the url in your browser with the API key. You can see the response.
Example :
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=your_api_key

Answer (score 0):

Found out this is due to extension 'stoplight' in their site. Site Manager has said

> *"I believe Stoplight has temporarily blocked the "Try it out" feature for our account because too many people were using it as the source
> for their apps, and not using api.themoviedb.org for some reason. No
> timeline on getting it restored, but that's the problem. - Travis Bell"*

follow this thread, In case it gets sorted in future.
https://www.themoviedb.org/talk/600184fc6aa8e0004077e364?page=1#6001bbacbe4b36003d514ac3

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it depends on the way you try to access the data.

In my React application I was using [Axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro).Which ended up with ReferenceError: response is not defined. (got no response)

Afterwards I tried using the [javascript fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). It worked good for me

So if you are trying to use it in an app you might want to use the fetch API. If you just encounter network error while using **Try it out** function on site - then you can copy the link and paste it directly, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I am using it in my dashboard and I have JWT authentication for the API that I'm using. I have implemented the interceptor to update  **HTTP HEADERS** so I saw I'm passing a header name 'token' and checked there if any unnecessary headers were given or not with not accepting the TMDB API server. So I have sent a clean HTTP request and it's working fine.

> All you have to just remove the unnecessary HTTP HEADERS